# redux-form unable to type values in fields

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I'm not able to type values in input fields using redux-form. I have the following reducer

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import session from './sessionReducer';
import profile from './profileReducer';
import map from './mapReducer';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    // short hand property names
    session,
    profile,
    map,
    form: formReducer
})

export default rootReducer;
```

and here is the store

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import createLogger from 'redux-logger'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import { routerReducer, routerMiddleware, push } from 'react-router-redux'
import reducers from '../reducers'
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

const middleware = [ thunk ];
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    middleware.push(createLogger());
}

middleware.push(routerMiddleware(browserHistory));


// Add the reducer to your store on the `routing` key
const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
        reducers,
        routing: routerReducer
    }),
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),

)

export default store;
```

component

```
import React, {PropTypes, Component} from 'react';
import Upload from './Upload';
import {bindActionCreators} from 'redux';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import * as profileActions from '../../../actions/profileActions';
import EventsCalendar from '../../common/EventsCalendar';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form'
import ProfileForm from './ProfileForm';

import {
    Form,
    FormGroup,
    FormControl,
    ControlLabel,
    Tabs,
    Tab,
    InputGroup,
    Label,
    HelpBlock,
    Grid,
    Row,
    Button,
    Col

} from 'react-bootstrap';


class Profile extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            profile: {
                username: '',
                password: '',
                email: ''
            }
        }
        //this.onUpdate = this.onUpdate.bind(this)
    }

    handleSubmit = (values) => {
        // Do something with the form values
        console.log(values);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.actions.getProfile()
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.profile !== this.props.profile) {

        }
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.profile);
        const {profile} = this.props.profile;
        const { handleSubmit } = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="row">
                <Col lg={10}>
                    <Tabs defaultActiveKey={1} id="uncontrolled-tab-example">
                        <Tab eventKey={1} title="Vendor Data">
                            <ProfileForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}  data = {this.props.profile}/>
                        </Tab>
                        <Tab eventKey={3} title="Events Calendar">
                            <EventsCalendar/>
                        </Tab>
                    </Tabs>

                </Col>

                <Col lg={2}>
                    <Upload/>
                </Col>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {

    return {
        profile: state.default.profile,
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(profileActions, dispatch)
    };
}

Profile = reduxForm({
    form: 'profileForm' // a unique name for this form
})(Profile);

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Profile);
```

when I'm typing I see in console that the state is changing

[image]

the attached form component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Field, reduxForm} from 'redux-form';
import FieldFormControl from '../../common/FieldFormControl';

import {
    FormGroup,
    FormControl,
    ControlLabel,
    Button

} from 'react-bootstrap';

class ProfileForm extends Component {
    render() {
        const {handleSubmit, profile, pristine, reset, submitting} = this.props;

        return (
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <FormGroup controlId="signup-name">
                    <Field type="text" name="firsname" placeholder="test" value component={FieldFormControl}>Vorname</Field>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup controlId="signup-username">
                    <Field type="text" name="lastname" placeholder={profile.username} value={profile.username} component={FieldFormControl}>Name</Field>
                </FormGroup>
                <FormGroup controlId="signup-email">
                    <Field type="text" name="email" placeholder={profile.username} value={profile.username} component={FieldFormControl}>Vorname</Field>
                </FormGroup>

                <Button
                    bsStyle="primary"
                    type="submit"
                    //disabled={pristine || submitting}
                    block
                >Speichern</Button>
            </form>
        );
    }
}

// Decorate the form component
ProfileForm = reduxForm({
    form: 'profileForm' // a unique name for this form
})(ProfileForm);

export default ProfileForm;
```

the bootstrap override to be compatible with redux-form

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {FormGroup, FormControl, ControlLabel} from 'react-bootstrap';

export default class FieldFormControl extends Component {

    render () {

        const { placeholder, type, input, meta} = this.props;

        return (
            <FormGroup controlId={input.name} validationState={meta.error ? 'error' : 'success'}>
                <ControlLabel>{this.props.children}</ControlLabel>
                <FormControl type={type} placeholder={placeholder} value={input.value} onChange={input.onChange} />
                <FormControl.Feedback />
            </FormGroup>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `value` prop from your `Field` components, redux-form handles updating the value and passing it to the `component` that you pass it. I'm assuming the idea here is to provide *initial* value, but this is not the place to do that.

```
<Field type="text" name="email" placeholder={profile.username} component={FieldFormControl}>Vorname</Field>
```

You can also pass all the `input` props to your `FormControl` in your `FieldFormControl` so you get `onFocus`, `onBlur`, etc., all provided by redux-form.

```
<FormControl placeholder={placeholder} {...input} />
```

If you want to initialize the fields with values, either use [`initialValues`](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/ReduxForm.md/#-initialvalues-object-string-string-optional-) when you connect using `reduxForm`, or [`initialize`](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/docs/api/Props.md/#-initialize-data-object-function-) if it needs to happen after the form mounts.

And finally, you're using `combineReducers` twice in such a way that most of your reducers are nested in a way that you didn't intend. To simplify this, I would import the `routerReducer` in your `reducers/index.js` file, and add it to your `combineReducers` there.

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    // short hand property names
    session,
    profile,
    map,
    form: formReducer,
    routing: routerReducer,
});
```

Then, in your store, you'll just have

```
const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
);
```

You should then see that you'll have all your keys in your state (session, profile, form, routing, etc.) instead of just default and routing.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and for the tipp! I was making the corrections but even like that I'm still not able to type values inside form fields. More of that I took the simple example form from redux-form docs site and does not work as well in my case. So obviously I make something wrong

Comment: Is your form inside the redux `Provider`?

Comment: yes `render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history} routes={routes} />
    </Provider>,
    target
);`

Comment: Ok, I see it. Your `rootReducer` isn't being added to your store correctly, which is why you don't have the correct keys in your state object. Updating the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is the redux-form's issue.

Instead, I think your application listens onChange of your input, and dispatch action to redux. So this is the root cause: you dispatch onChange action, causing the redux state to update, (I think your code has not change it in reducer) and after that, redux flushes the render UI.

To fix it, you:
typically, when you dispatch the onChange action, in your reducer, update yuor redux state explicitly. then new state will flush your UI automatically.

e.g. your reducer should have similar like this:

```
function myReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case MY_INPUT_VALUE_CHANGE:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        vornname: action.data
      })
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for feedback! Where and how do I update the state?

Comment: hey, it's way of redux works: http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Reducers.html i have updated my answer example code

Comment: thanks I got the idea between just I'm not able to figure out how do I deal with async data. I use thunk as middleware, and I get the initial data via ajax. Now how do I dispatch form actions is a bit unclear as learning this things.

Comment: The provided reducer that you are correctly using handles updating the for state for you, as you can see in your action log. Are you familiar with redux-form @Xin? Using its reducer to handle form state for you is the usual usage. @fefe the issue may be in the `component` you're using with your `Field` components. Please show your form component.

Comment: I will attach the component, is an override to be usable with bootstrap